# Display Order in H.264 encoded video Syntax

Tags: video, compression, h.264

Can anybody please help me understand how POC(Picture Order Count) works? How topFieldOrderCount and bottomFieldOrderCount help to come up with proper display order of a picture (frame or field) in H.264 encoded video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The correct algorithm is:
Keep a buffer of size=(num_reorder_frames+1).
Put each newly decoded frame into the buffer.
Whenever the buffer is full, remove the frame with the lowest {idr_pic_id,poc}
(where idr_pic_id is a monotonically increasing value, not  literally the variable idr_pic_id from the standard).

This gives you the pictures in display order.

(poc is calculated using pic_order_cnt_lsb)

See: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2006-August/007255.html